# if else imacros statement

Tags: if-statement, imacros

i don't know how to use it ?

```js
i = iimPlay("#current",60);

s = iimGetLastExtract();
if (s.indexOf ("Your Answer") != -1)
    iimplay ("9kweu_media",60);
else
    iimplay ("recaptcha_v2cap:"+s);
```

Comment: If `s.indexOf ("Your Answer") != -1` evaluates to true then `iimplay ("9kweu_media",60);` is executed otherwise the `iimplay ("recaptcha_v2cap:"+s);`.

Comment: but it doesn't work played current  and then stops